# gateway addr in netstat -r output not shown as an IP but literally as "gateway"

Tags: linux, networking, redhat

when executing `netstat -r` the output reads:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.100.200.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
```

So instead of the IP of our gateway there is the name gateway, which is ping able for us with the correct IP being looked up somewhere.

My question is, where is this configured and how do I stop that? Because it's not in /etc/hosts nor is it in our DNS and I wanna see an IP there and not some generic name.

EDIT:

I wanna clarify that I know that other tools don't necessarily do that, I just wanna know where this name for the gateway IP is configured.

`dig -x` excerpt

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;254.200.100.10.in-addr.arpa.    IN      PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
```

OS Used: CentOS - 7.2.1511 - 3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64

Comment: You should try `route -n` or `netstat -r -n` or `ip -h route`

Comment: I know that other tools don't do that, but I still wanna know where this gateway name is coming from.

Comment: It may be "configured" as a PTR by your provider. You may have no power over it. Try `dig -x <numric ip>` to confirm

Comment: "gateway" is the hostname of your... well, gateway. I checked for me and it says "router" and then I remembered that I configured "router" to be the hostname of our router so I don't have to type the IP all the time. Check the /etc/hostname of your gatway or check the GUI (depending on what type of system your gateway is) if you want to know more.

Comment: Even better `grep -R gateway /etc`

Comment: interesting, because the gateway in our case is a firewall and it has a completely different hostname

Comment: Ok, I would like to know more details. As far as I understand you get this output on a server in your network? However, this can only come from a hostname entry, a hosts file or a static or dynamic DNS table, these are your 4 options. Maybe the firewall has a second DNS running? More infos on what systems are used and how they are connected would help.

Comment: `getent hosts gateway` If it resolves, then the solution is in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: `getent hosts gateway` does resolve, in nsswitch.conf this is configured: "hosts:      files dns myhostname", but there is no /etc/hosts entry and there is no reverse lookup for this IP configured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ipor Sircer said in his comment the solution was in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. There these three were configured for host: `files dns myhostname`. Files and DNS I've already checked and I had no real idea what myhostname did, except the obvious.

As it turns out it also does this:

> The hostname "gateway" is resolved to all current default routing
>   gateway addresses, ordered by their metric.

Source --> [libnss_myhostname.so.2](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-myhostname.html)

So in order to resolv this I'll have to create a file/DNS entry or remove myhostname from `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Btw thanks for the quick brainstorm in the comments ;-)